# Group and count from joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a row per learner, with the following format:

```
nsn|last_name|first_name|middle_name|gender|ethnicities|providers|qualifications|vocation_PI|vocation_SI|.....
```

A Learner has many providers, a provider has many learners
At each provider, a learner has many results, results belong to one learner
A result has one standard, a standard belongs to none/many results
A standard has many vocations

```
select l.nsn, l.last_name,l.first_name,l.middle_name, l.gender, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct e.name SEPARATOR '|') as ethnicities, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct p.name SEPARATOR '|') as providers, count(case v.code when 'PI' then 1 else 0 end) as v_PI,count(case v.code when 'SI' then 1 else 0 end) as v_SI,count(case v.code when 'CR' then 1 else 0 end) as v_CR, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct q.name SEPARATOR '|') as qualifications
from learners l 
join learner_ethnicity le on l.id = le.learner_id
join ethnicities e on le.ethnicity_id = e.id
join learner_provider lp on l.id = lp.learner_id
join providers p on lp.provider_id = p.id
join results r on lp.id = r.learner_provider_id
join standards s on r.standard_id = s.id
join standard_vocation sv on s.id = sv.standard_id
join vocations v on sv.vocation_id = v.id
join learner_qualification lq on l.id = lq.learner_id
join qualifications q on lq.qualification_id = q.id
group by l.id
```

I can't get the count for each vocation to work.

I get the same value in each count field (not sure if this is a total of all counts or what)

Expected output:

```
123451234 | Doe | John | James | M | European|Maori | SecondaryProvider|TertiaryProvider | NCEA Level 1|NCEA Level 2|Farming PHD | 185 | 430 | .....
```

Actual output:

```
123451234 | Doe | John | James | M | European|Maori | SecondaryProvider|TertiaryProvider | NCEA Level 1|NCEA Level 2|Farming PHD | 500 | 500 | .....
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REPLACE YOUR COUNT WITH SUM YOU WILL GET WHAT YOU WANT

```
select l.nsn, l.last_name,l.first_name,l.middle_name, l.gender, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct e.name SEPARATOR '|') as ethnicities, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct p.name SEPARATOR '|') as providers, sum(case v.code when 'PI' then 1 else 0 end) as v_PI, sum(case v.code when 'SI' then 1 else 0 end) as v_SI,sum(case v.code when 'CR' then 1 else 0 end) as v_CR, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct q.name SEPARATOR '|') as qualifications
from learners l 
join learner_ethnicity le on l.id = le.learner_id
join ethnicities e on le.ethnicity_id = e.id
join learner_provider lp on l.id = lp.learner_id
join providers p on lp.provider_id = p.id
join results r on lp.id = r.learner_provider_id
join standards s on r.standard_id = s.id
join standard_vocation sv on s.id = sv.standard_id
join vocations v on sv.vocation_id = v.id
join learner_qualification lq on l.id = lq.learner_id
join qualifications q on lq.qualification_id = q.id
group by l.id
```

Comment: count(case v.code when 'PI' then 1 else 0 end) if you check this it will give 1 or 0 value and your taking the count of it it will equal to total count